# Selenium WebDriver - Chrome - C# - Unable to launch selenium browser in Incognito Mode as a maximised browser

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium suite which has 150 test cases. The test has to run in Incognito mode in Chrome Browser.

I am able to launch the browser in incognito Mode. But the issue is the browser is not getting maximized ( say for 10 test cases and for remaining 140 test cases the browser launches in maximized mode) , though there is a code to maximize the browser.

As a result of this, some of the test fails ( All 10 test ).

Below is my code

```
                desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument(@"--incognito");
                options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
                desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
                webDriver = new MyWebDriver(new Uri(gridHubURL), options.ToCapabilities(),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.RemoteDriverTimeOutValue),testContext);
                break;
```

Is there a way to ensure that the browser always (100%) launches in maximised mode.

The click operation fails when the browser is not maximised.

**System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (886, 466). Other element would receive the click:**

For this reason, I want to run in maximised mode. In maximised mode, I am not getting this error. Please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--incognito");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C://",options);
```

It works for me

Answer (score 2):

Could do something like this:

```
desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(@"--incognito");
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
webDriver = new MyWebDriver(new Uri(gridHubURL), options.ToCapabilities(),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.RemoteDriverTimeOutValue),testContext);

webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 break;
```

It will need to be after the `webDriver` opens up, but it will maximize the window for you.

Try this instead, I have tested and should be fine

```
  var caps = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
            var options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.AddArgument(@"--incognito");
            options.AddArgument(@"--start-maximized");
            caps.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);



            var webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://yourURL.com");
            webdriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Comment: I tried this but resulted in exception. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the edits. If still exception please post exception so we can locate the issue

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to set the initial size:

```
options.AddArgument("--window-size=1024,768");
```

You could also set some extreme values. The window should then have the size of the screen since the OS limits it (at least on Windows) :

```
options.AddArgument("--window-size=32000,32000");
```